# Renaming package with the same package name across 4 repositories

Tags: java, eclipse, git, intellij-idea

I have 4 repositories that have the same package names in them such as:

```
com.companyname.ateam.uiautomation
```

Each is in 4 repositories (Utils, WebDriver, Page, Test).
I want to rename the packages to actually be useful for each repository.
Then my next step is to merge at least 'page' and 'tests' into the same repositories.

In IntelliJ I have tried `refactor.rename` and `refactor.move`. It seems that since they all import from each other that the IDE just goes in and renames everything it finds with the package name and breaks the imports/references.

I spent a little time in Eclipse trying as well and it breaks the same things.
I a have also tried rename and move for asingle directory inside the package with the same results.

Has anyone dealt with this have a solution or tips? Many google searches haven't turned up this situation.

Answer (score 1):

For those in the future. I didn't find a clean/intelligent way of doing this. I had to go the manual route.
For each repo I had to:

- Add new package
- Drag assets into new package
- Build package and manually and find an replace reference issues.

The refactor rename caused many more issues and I couldn't find a cleaner way of doing this. It was time intensive. Thank you for all that read.

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone dealt with this have a solution or tips? Many google searches haven't turned up this situation.

Use the `git filter-branch` command

#### git filter-branch

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'sed <do what you want to do in here on your files>'
```

Comment: Thanks CodeWizard. I'm not familiar with 'git filter-branch'. I talked to a team member who better with git than me, we tried a few things but didn't get far. We are though confused how it is going to work or how it is going to both:
1. Rename the package
2. Edit the references/imports statements to only the one package and not the other references in the 3 repos that are of the same name. 

C:\TestRepo\com.companyname.ateam.uiautomation\tests
C:\DriverRepo\com.companyname.ateam.uiautomation\driver

So files in tests import classes from driver.